# How two applications can interact with each other?

Tags: integration, communication, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two RoR applications (app1, app2) and I would like them communicate with each other. This means that I want send requests between app1 and app2, each with its own database.

On my local machine (Mac OS Snow Leopard v10.6.5) I set up correctly Ruby on Rails and Phusion Passenger in order to have access to the following URL:

- http:// < app1_name >.local
- http:// < app2_name >.local

Now, what should I do to make the two applications can interact with each other?

What is the best practice for doing this? Creating and using API or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveResource is probably what you want to look at:

[Screencast1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics)
[Screencast2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement REST services and call them from applications. It should ge very easy to do e.g. http://www.docstoc.com/docs/23965370/RESTful-XML-Web-Services-with-Ruby-on-Rails